# Group with $f(x)=x^{4k+3}$ endomorphism and $(xy)^{2^{s}}$=$(yx)^{2^{s}}$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group and $n=4k+3$ where $k$ is a positive integer, such that the function
$f : G \rightarrow G$, $f(x)=x^{n}$ is an endomorphism.
We denote by $M=\{m\in \mathbb{N}|(xy)^{m}=(yx)^{m}, \forall x,y \in G \}$. 
Prove that, if there exists $s \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^s \in M$, then $G$ is abelian.

Progress: We have that $(yx)^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}$, so $y^{n}x^{n}=(yx)^n=yxx^{n-1}y^{n-1}$ and therefore,
$y^{n-1}x^{n}=x^{n}y^{n-1}$ $\forall x, y \in G$. It follows that $$(xy)^{n(n-1)}=(x^{n}y^{n})^{n-1}=y^{n(n-1)}x^{n(n-1)}=x^{n(n-1)}y^{n(n-1)}=(y^{n}x^{n})^{n-1}=(yx)^{n(n-1)}$$ $\forall x, y \in G$  , so we have that $n(n-1) \in M$   

We know that $(2^{s}, n(n-1))=2$, so there exist $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^{s}u+n(n-1)v=2$. Then it results that $$(xy)^{2}=(xy)^{2^{s}u+n(n-1)v}=(yx)^{2^{s}u+n(n-1)v}=(yx)^{2}$$ so $2 \in M$. 
If we let $y\rightarrow yx^{-1}$ then $xy^2=y^2x$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^2 \in Z(G)$ $ \forall x \in G$.

Comment: Isn't $x^n = e$ for all $x \in G$? Then $x \mapsto x^n$ is trivially an endomorphism but I do not see how it is relevant.

Comment: I apologise, i have edited the problem.

Comment: Also, why do you have $(yx)^{n-1} = x^{n-1} y^{n-1}$? By the endomorphism you only have $x^n y^n = (xy)^n$.

Comment: In $ (xy)^n=x^ny^n$ we multiply with $x^{-1}$ at left and $y^{-1}$ at right